# How to keep Flashlight ON while press on home button?

Tags: java, android, service, flashlight, background-service

I am developing a very simple flashlight application, while I have successfully achieved what I was looking for, I would like to perform it that way I want it to. Currently my flashlight remains on while my activity is active, as soon as I hit the home button to minimize the activity flashlight turns off. I want the flashlight to stay on and turn off only when I click the turn off button in my activity.

```
public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity {


ImageButton btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

    /*
     * First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
     */
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlashLightActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();

    /*
     * Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
     */
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Get the camera
 */
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Turning On flash
 */
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}

/*
 * Turning Off flash
 */
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}

/*
 * Playing sound
 * will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
 * */
private void playSound(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(FlashLightActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(FlashLightActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 
    mp.start();
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: remove turnOffFlash(); from onPause() methode

Comment: remove the code form on resume since you have binded the turn of feature to lifecycle of activity therefore it will turn off when you minimize as onPause is called.And for implementation you have to stop activity getting killed.

Comment: when you minimize the app it enters inside the onpause methode, and you are turning off flash in onPause methode

Comment: ok. Thanks Dear. @Piyush & sud

Comment: @piyush Can U write code for Flashlight ON when press home button?

Comment: you have to start a service which stop your application to get killed when in background start fore ground service